# iOS crash 'failed to generate newParagraphStyle'

Tags: ios, objective-c

After I add a library (a internal common library) to my project I received the following crash:

> *** Assertion failure in -[_UICascadingTextStorage setTextAlignment:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/TextSystem/_UICascadingTextStorage.m:270
>
> Project[784:18448] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'failed to generate newParagraphStyle'

I can't find what are the reasons for the type of crash or what I did wrong for this.

Note: I added the Libray but I haven't yet used any features from library.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean build?

Comment: Yes, I did. After start the Application I receive the exception that I mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library may call `+initialize` or `+load` or do some general swizzling/overriding of Apple classes and it can mess something up, e.g. in a new iOS version, if APIs changed.

If you have the src for the library, look for those things.

Also create an exception breakpoint, maybe it will point you to the problem in code.

Comment: I found the problem. It was a category defined on the library: UIFont+TradeGothic.

Comment: `(UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:fontSize];
}`

This is the reason to the app crash, Anyone know what is the workaround for this?

Comment: stop using or fix the library?

Comment: I need use this library because it contains the source code to a component that I need integrate on my application. My question is how I can fix this? Because is a requirement has custom font on the app.